# What is the 'Go' button on a page of a set of forms called?

Tags: buttons, terminology

The user has completed a form in a set of forms.

Or made some option choices.

The button, bottom right, loads the next form.

What's the correct generic name for this button?

(I called it the 'Go' button.)

Comment: Is each form independently saved or are all forms saved after the last form/page like a survey?

Comment: Independently.  It's a registration sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just a [submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)? If it's loading another form, I would be inclined to label it 'Next' instead of 'Go', especially if it's possible to go back. It looks like you're essentially building a [wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) of some sorts.

Comment: I think 'Submit' covers it.  Next would imply that there's also a Back button. Which there isn't.